# How can I pass both id and value to the controller from my input form in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, httprequest, cakephp-2.0

Here is my code

View (edit.ctp):

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Answer'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Answer.0.value', array('class' => 'validate', 'type' => 'text', 'id' => 'Answer.0.id', 'label' => false)) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Edit Answer'); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $this->layout = 'request_processing_edit';
    $data = $this->Response->findById($id);
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Response->id = $id;
        if ($this->Answer->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Answer Editted');
            $this->redirect('index');
        }
}
```

This is how $this->request->data array looks like:

[I need the id to be in the same array as value upon clicking submit in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEjkV.jpg)

Is there any way to achieve this without having to build the array in the controller?  Looking for a way to have both id and value passed in the request upon clicking submit from the view/form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Here you can use this way

In your Controller :

```
$data = $this->Post->findById($id);

if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $this->Answer->id = $id;
    if ($this->Answer->save($this->request->data)) {
         $this->Session->setFlash('Answer Editted');
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
     $this->Session->setFlash('Answer Not Editted');
}

if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = $data;
```

In Your View File Pass Hidden Field ID :

```
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by adding this line of code in my ctp file:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Answer.0.id', array('hidden' => true)) ?>
```